# How to edit Workflow steps via API?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

In my solution I have a workflow where one step contains a reference to Queue. After importing this solution on another CRM instance this workflow could not be activated because it contains an invalid reference - Queue can not be resolved. Queue with same name is created on new CRM but resolving is probably based on record Guid.

Now, I'm wondering, is there a way to edit workflow steps using CRM SDK? Whole process of CRM solution deployment is automated. And I want to remove all manual work. Some example would be great :)

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things you can do if you are having issues with the Guids not matching in a workflow lookup when deploying from one environment to another.

1. Use the API to create those records referenced in the WF.  When you create a record you can actually specify the Guid that it uses as the id.  So write a tool or see if one exists already that will create some default data for your environment.
2. Use a configuration entity with references to all the EntityRefrences needed in your WFs.  Then you can create a custom workflow activity to retrieve the configuration entity record (there should only ever really be one) that contains all the references in that environment.